# Problems installing VirtualΒox extension

Tags: virtualbox, extension

I decided to update Virtualbox and the Virtualbox extension. I am having trouble though, while trying to introduce them to each other with no success. This is the error message I get when trying to load Virtualbox:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (4.4.0-143-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Well, that didn't work. I think mainly because it is trying to load 4.4.0-143-generic and what I downloaded was 5.2.26 to match my version of Virtualbox. If I try to install using Virtualbox, it claims that the extension was installed correctly but, when I try to actually run Virtualbox, I get the error message above. When I let Virtualbox download the new extension, I have no idea where it goes but it seems like Virtualbox is trying to install the old extension. I finally downloaded the correct extension, which Virtualbox claims installed properly but, when I try to load Virtualbox I again get that same error message.
Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks

Sorry about that Charles Green. Here is the output from sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run /sbin/vboxconfig as root.

Comment: The "4.4.0-143-generic" is the version of the Linux kernel that you are running, and unrelated to the "5.2.26" version of VirtualBox that you are trying to get loaded.  If you run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, what error messages do you recieve?

Comment: Please also execute the command `apt list virtualbox* --installed` and copy the output of that command, and paste it into your original question.

Comment: Okay, I ran that command and here is what turned up:

apt list virtualbox* --installed 
Listing... Done
virtualbox-5.2/unknown,now 5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~xenial amd64 [installed]

But, when I try to load Virtual box, I get the same error message.

Comment: K - two things:  1st (most important) please *edit your question* and add requested data there, not in the comments!  2nd) It does appear that 5.2.26 is installed - when you ran `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` were there any error messages?